# How to write a C++ concept restricting the template to std::map and std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

If I have a templates looking like this that perform a simple operation of copying for the sake of example but for `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`:

```cpp
template<typename T1, typename T2>
inline std::map<T1, T2> map_copy(std::map<T1,T2> const& a) {
  std::map<T1,T2> output;
  output = a;
  return output;
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
inline std::unordered_map<T1, T2> map_copy(std::unordered_map<T1,T2> const& a) {
  std::unordered_map<T1,T2> output;
  output = a;
  return output;
}
```

Is there a way, probably using C++ concepts, to reduce these definitions to just one, constraining the possible types just to `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this concept to check if a type is a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept map_type = 
    std::same_as<T, std::map<typename T::key_type, typename T::mapped_type, typename T::key_compare, typename T::allocator_type>> ||
    std::same_as<T, std::unordered_map<typename T::key_type, typename T::mapped_type, typename T::hasher, typename T::key_equal, typename T::allocator_type>>;
    
template<map_type T>
T map_copy(T const& a) {
    T output;
    output = a;
    return output;
}
```

For generic checking if `T` is an instantiation of `template<typename...> struct Template;`, you could do something like:

```cpp
template<template<typename...> class Template, typename Class>
struct is_instantiation : std::false_type {};

template<template<typename...> class Template, typename... Args>
struct is_instantiation<Template, Template<Args...>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename Class, template<typename...> class Template>
concept is_instantiation_of = is_instantiation<Template, Class>::value;

template<typename T>
concept map_type =
    is_instantiation_of<T, std::map> || is_instantiation_of<T, std::unordered_map>;

template<map_type T>
T map_copy(T const& a) {
    T output;
    output = a;
    return output;
}

template<is_instantiation_of<std::map> T>
T ordered_map_copy(T const& a) {
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I wonder if there is no such helper in a standard library...

Comment: @AntonKochkov i think it was either a candidate to std::experimental or to boost library, at least it gives deja vue

Comment: Although it only works when a template's parameters are all type parameters. For example, it can't detect a `std::array` specialization.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a constraint,

```
template<template <typename...> class MAP, typename T1, typename T2>
inline MAP<T1, T2> map_copy(MAP<T1,T2> const& a) 
  requires std::is_same_v<MAP<T1,T2>, std::map<T1,T2>> || 
    std::is_same_v<MAP<T1,T2>, std::unordered_map<T1,T2>> {
  MAP<T1,T2> output;
  output = a;
  return output;
}
```

Or define a concept,

```
template<template <typename...> class MAP, typename T1, typename T2>
concept Mappable = std::is_same_v<MAP<T1,T2>, std::map<T1,T2>> ||
  std::is_same_v<MAP<T1,T2>, std::unordered_map<T1,T2>>;
```

then

```
template <template <typename...> class MAP, typename T1, typename T2>
inline MAP<T1, T2> map_copy(MAP<T1,T2> const& a) requires Mappable<MAP, T1, T2> {
  MAP<T1,T2> output;
  output = a;
  return output;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to extract the concept restriction into a separate clause with `concept Mappable = requires {...}`?

Comment: @AntonKochkov Yes, answer revised.

Comment: You could also create a concept taking just the container type as argument - maybe more useful if you have multiple declarations that would be using it. Its definition would need to use a helper trait.

Comment: @aschepler I think it'd be a good idea to provide an answer with alternative approach - the one you suggested.

Comment: This is not a good concept. Usually what you want with concepts is not "is it of this particular type?" but rather "can this type be used the way I'm using them?"

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use this conception:

```
template <typename Container>
concept Associative = requires(Container cont) {
    typename Container::key_type;
    typename Container::mapped_type;
    { cont.begin() } -> std::same_as<typename Container::iterator>;
    { cont.end() } -> std::same_as<typename Container::iterator>;
};

template<Associative Container>
void func(const Container& cont) {
  // ...
}
```